# cakePhp framework in netbeans not working

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, ide

I am learning cakePhp framework. I want to netbeans as IDE. But only ZEND and symphony frameworks shown to be available. But cakephp is not even shown. I installed plugin, restarted netbeans IDE but still not working. Any suggestion how to fix the problem

Comment: You need to define in your question what thing is not working. What are you trying, what is happening and what are you expecting?

Comment: Try following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3g4ld2jzbU&feature=youtu.be) screencast.

Comment: Take in account that it will ONLY appear to NEW projects, if you create a new project with existing files, it will not asks you, you have to select it on project properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some problem relate to cakephp-netbeans plugin, please submit them to [github issue tracker](https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp-netbeans/issues?state=open).

I need some information.

- environments (e.g. OS, NetBeans version, plugin version)
- steps (detail)
- screenshots (if possible)
- e.t.c

Thanks.